# Multiple file value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to get names of all the files being browsed through file input.

For a single file I know this :

```
var validfile=document.forms["filesharing"]["file"].value;
```

But problem is what if i have multiple files browsed ?

HTML :

```
<form method=post action="stegnographyonshares" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return formvalidations()" name="filesharing"> 
    <input type="file" name="file" value="file" id="file" multiple="multiple"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: Please show the HTML of the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access using the files property of file upload control.

```
var lstFiles = document.forms["filesharing"]["file"].files;

for(var i=0; i < lstFiles.length; i++) {
    var f = lstFiles[i];

    alert(f.name);
}
```

Comment: Sorry its wrong,Its returning [ObjectData] when i alert f in this loop

Comment: @user3704229 What you exactly want to do?

Comment: I want name of all files browsed in an array.